# Finding the exact area bound between the curves $kx^2$, and $\sqrt {kx}$, where $K$ is not given.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

[image: aaaa]
[image]

I attempted to solve this question as you can see above (in the second image) by integrating the two functions from 0, where the area begins, and then the point where they equal each other, point Q. However I have absolutely no idea if this is the correct way to go about it since I cant find any similar worked questions in my textbooks or on the internet.

Did I completely go about this the wrong way? Have I written down the question wrong and its actually just unsolvable? I am not sure, and I would appreciate some help.

Comment: You're overloading $x$: it's in the bounds of integration and as the integration variable.

Comment: First solve $f(x)=g(x)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st of all the subtraction is in the wrong direction because for small numbers $x^2$ is less than $\sqrt{x}$.  Also you need to integrate to the upper bound Q.  You can solve for Q based on k by solving for the value of x where they cross.

$$kx^2 = \sqrt{kx}$$

$$kx^2 = \sqrt{k}\sqrt{x}$$
$$x^{3/2} = \frac{\sqrt{k}}{k} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$$
$$ Q = x = (k^{-1/2})^{2/3} = k^{-1/3}$$

Now just finish by doing the integrals.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's easiest to write this as a double integral. So,  first you need to find the points where $kx^2 = \sqrt{kx}$. Square both sides and factorise to arrive at $kx(kx^3 - 1) = 0$, which has solutions when $x = 0$ and when $x = k^{-1/3}$. Then write your region in the $x-y$ plane as

$$
D = \{ (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 : 0 \leq x \leq k^{-1/3}, kx^2 \leq y  \leq \sqrt{kx}\}
$$

Now you can write your area as

$$
R = \int\int_D dxdy = \int_0^{k^{-1/3}}\int_{kx^2}^{\sqrt{kx}}dy dx  = \int_0^{k^{-1/3}}\sqrt{kx} -kx^2dx = \frac{1}{3}
$$
I assume you know how to solve the last integral to get $\frac{1}{3}$.

So we see in the end that the answer is independent of $k$ for all $k>0$, perhaps surprisingly.

Answer (score 0):

I would go about the interval bounderies in a different way.
First, notice that $k$ must be non negative, otherwise $g(x)$ is not well defind.

Next, notice that $f(0) = k \cdot 0^2 = 0$ and $g(0) = \sqrt{k \cdot 0} = 0$.
Moreover, both functions are strictly montone increasing on $[0, \infty)$. Thus, we can easily calculate their intersect in terms of $k$. Notice, that finding $Q$ was given as a hint in the exercise itself.
Finding the intersect:
$$f(x) = g(x) \Leftrightarrow kx^2 = \sqrt{kx} \Leftrightarrow k^2x^4 = kx \Leftrightarrow x^3 = \frac{1}{k} \Leftrightarrow x = (\frac{1}{k})^{\frac{1}{3}}$$

Now, notice that on the interval $(0, (\frac{1}{k})^{\frac{1}{3}})$ $g(x) > f(x)$

Thus, to calculate your area, set up your integrals as follows:

$$\int_0^{(\frac{1}{k})^{\frac{1}{3}}} g(x)dx - \int_0^{(\frac{1}{k})^{\frac{1}{3}}} f(x)dx$$

Now, simply integrate and you recieve your area.